# PHP SDK Requires two logins...doesn't recognize first

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, sdk

I am using the following code to authenticate whether users are logged in or not. While users can log in, they have to click the login button twice. Additionally, sometimes even after they click the log-in button twice, my "user info" part of the page (earlier in the page than the content) shows them as logged out while the actual page shows them as logged in.

Here is the code. Could someone suggest a better way of handling log-ins?

```
function isLoggedIn($facebook) {
    if (isset($facebook) and $facebook->getUser() != 0) {
        // UserID exists, but user may still not be logged in. Let's check:
        try {
            $facebook->api('/me', 'GET');
            // If this succeeds, then they are logged in.
            return true;
        } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
            // Some kind of error, so not logged in.
            if(session_id() === '')
                session_destroy();
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        if(session_id() === '')
            session_destroy();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is your app on Facebook (Canvas Page)?

Comment: No, it's a website on its own.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem! And I am finding no answer's anywhere :( did you get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array( /* the data */));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if($user) {
  //loged
} else {
  //not loged
}
```

is enough

Answer (score 0):

Well here is a quick fix ... maybe dirty but I needed to get it to work. Having to click twice is ridiculous.

```
    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    if($user) {
        // do stuff cause user is now logged 
    }
    if(isset($_GET['fb_logged']) && $user == 0) {
        // not logged, would have to click twice but let's help that user.
        header('Location: '.$loginUrl);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I was initiating $facebook instances two times, resolved by using one and added "offline_access" and it worked so far, now working with one login click only

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array( /* the data */));
```

Comment: `offline_access` permission has been removed quite a while ago already, so please don’t recommend it any more.